# Testing cassandra Session.State - how to mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, cassandra

Im looking at this function:

```
Session.State state = session.getState();
if(state.getConnectedHosts().size() == 0)
    return  Result.unhealthy("No cassandra connections");
else return Result.healthy();
```

I'd like to test the various conditions here but I'm not clear on how to mock/simulate/deal with the **Session.State** value. I can mock the **session** but the other is an interface - at runtime it's a **SessionManager** that lacks public access.

Is there a way to (Power)Mock this? Another avenue to test this?

Comment: If you can mock the session.getState, then you should be able to return a Session.State from it...

Answer (score 0):

Using [Mockito](http://mockito.org/), the following works for me:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

Session session = mock(Session.class);        
Session.State state = mock(Session.State.class);
when(session.getState()).thenReturn(state);
when(state.getConnectedHosts()).thenReturn(Collections.<Host>emptyList());
```